# Show Databases Statement is DDL,DML or Others?

Tags: database

I am little bit confuse about `show Databases` statement is DDL,DML or Other? I what to know the details info about this.Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

[**DML:**](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/what_are_the_difference_between_ddl_dml_and_dcl_commands)

> Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements are used for managing data
>   within schema objects.

[**DDL:**](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/what_are_the_difference_between_ddl_dml_and_dcl_commands)

> Data Definition Language (DDL) statements are used to define the
>   database structure or schema. Some examples:

Since DML talks about the `objects in schema of database` and DDL talks about the `structure of database or schema`, I think show databases belongs to none of them.

So, it should in **others**.

**Show statements are basically of different types like:**

```
show triggers [database name] [some other info];
show databases;
show priveleges;
```

They actually belong to the [Database Administration Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-server-administration.html)

[Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_1001.htm)

[How to find whether the SQL query type is DML or DDL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332388/how-to-find-whether-the-sql-query-type-is-dml-or-ddl)